Setting Full Height for Table Body in Next.js UI Without Distorting Layout
import React from "react";
import {Table, TableHeader, TableColumn, TableBody, TableRow, TableCell} from "@nextui-org/react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Table aria-label="Example static collection table">
      <TableHeader>
        <TableColumn>NAME</TableColumn>
        <TableColumn>ROLE</TableColumn>
        <TableColumn>STATUS</TableColumn>
      </TableHeader>
      <TableBody>
        <TableRow key="1">
          <TableCell>Tony Reichert</TableCell>
          <TableCell>CEO</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Active</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow key="2">
          <TableCell>Zoey Lang</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Technical Lead</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Paused</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow key="3">
          <TableCell>Jane Fisher</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Senior Developer</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Active</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow key="4">
          <TableCell>William Howard</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Community Manager</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Vacation</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  );
}

I'm working on a Next.js project and encountered an issue with setting the full height for the table body without causing layout distortions. I'm using Next.js UI for my frontend components. Currently, when I try to set the height of the table body to 100%, it ends up messing up the layout. How can I achieve a full height for the table body within the Next.js UI framework without encountering this problem? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
